# How to prevent message handling after the control's destruction

Tags: delphi, access-violation, windows-messages, object-destruction

There are two instances of the following component types:

1. `TfrmTimeSliceStructure`, which is a direct descendant of `TFrame`.
2. `THKSDBVirtualStringTree`, which is a direct descendant of `TDBVirtualStringTree` (from FIBPlus), which itself is a direct descendant of Mike Lischke's `TVirtualStringTree` class.

The `THKSDBVirtualStringTree` component is used as a child control on `TfrmTimeSliceStructure`.

On a double click - under certain conditions - the frame shall be destroyed.

For this I do a `PostMessage` call with a custom message code `WM_USER + 4` (this is hexadecimal `$0404`), so that the destruction is delayed until all current messages are handled completely.

Though, in many cases an access violation occurs, as the `THKSDBVirtualStringTree` component is still handling messages after its own destruction.

I expected that there is no message handling happening after a control's destruction.

**How can I prevent messages to be handled by a control that has already been destroyed?**

Below, you can see the debugger's output. In both classes, I added a message logging in the method `WndProc` to output the recieved message code. In the first line, one can see that my custom message code `WM_USER + 4` has been recieved.

Some lines later, there are two lines `Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree is going to be destroyed.` and `Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree has been destroyed.`. In between these two lines, no messages are recieved.
After these lines, there are still some messages handled. Eventually, this leads to the access violation at the end. From their message codes I can see, that those messages are control messages, because `CM_BASE = $B000;`.

```
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $0404 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $0405 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $8001 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $0200 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $0202 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $0215 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $02A3 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B014 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $B014 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $8001 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $8001 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 6260. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 21148. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 6260. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $0002 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $000E Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $0272 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $0002 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $000E Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $0082 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class TfrmTimeSliceStructure recieved message $0082 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree is going to be destroyed. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 22156. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree has been destroyed. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 5672. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B028 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Start: Thread-ID: 9244. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B009 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B008 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B023 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B03D Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B050 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B058 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B011 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B03B Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B03B Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B00D Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B022 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B009 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B008 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B023 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B035 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B03D Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B050 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B058 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B011 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B009 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B035 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B034 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B009 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B03B Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B008 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B00E Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B034 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B008 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B00E Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B034 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 5672. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Thread-Ende: Thread-ID: 21148. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Debug-Ausgabe: Instance of class THKSDBVirtualStringTree recieved message $B007 Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
Erste Gelegenheit für Exception bei $01819981. Exception-Klasse $C0000005 mit Meldung 'access violation at 0x01819981: read of address 0x00000050'. Prozess Memory.exe (20916)
```

Comment: Hard to give general advice here. If I were faced with the problem, I'd want to be debugging a reproduction.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'll try to provide an MCVE. But was my exception about message handling not happening after a control's destruction at least correct?

Comment: Have you tried to call the frame's Release method rather than Free? It is meant for exactly that purpose. (I don't know whether this will solve the problem though, just a thought.

Comment: @dummzeuch, a frame does not have a `Release` method. OP implemented its own. same as Form's  `Release` (I would have used `CM_RELEASE` instead of `WM_USER`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused by an explicit call to `Application.ProcessMessages` somewhere in our `OnNodeDblClick` event handler code.

Unfortunately, we still have some of these calls in our code base. :-(

---

Let me tell you how I found out the problem's cause:

As you can see in the question, I tried these two approaches:

1. Override the control's `WndProc` and log every processed message with `OutputDebugString`.
2. Check, whether the control has already been destroyed, by adding one call to `OutputDebugString` to the beginning and another to the end of your control's destructor.

Later, it came to my mind to...

3. ...check, whether the initiating user interaction (here: a double click) has been processed completely. This is to be done with `OutputDebugString`, too.
   In my case, the second mouse-down was not completely handled before the access violation occured.

I could then conclude, that somewhere the message queue is prematurely processed. So, I had to find out, where `Application.ProcessMessages` is called.

4. Therefore, I added a breakpoint in this method. Because a normal breakpoint would have broken the message processing. I used another breakpoint type, which - I have to confess - I used the first time at all.
   In the breakpoint's *advanced settings* I deselected *Break* and selected *Log Call Stack* instead. I decided to log only two stack frames, because I just wanted to know who the direct caller of `Application.ProcessMessages` is.

After another round of reproduction, I had an extensive debugger log containing all those handled message codes and lines for each call to the mouse-down handler, the object's destructor and every call to `Application.ProcessMessages`.

5. Now, I could infer that the first call to `Application.ProcessMessages` after the beginning of the unfinished mouse-down handler and before the reception of my custom event `WM_USER + 4` has to be the one, which breaks the code.

Comment: Hard to see why you've written this answer. We don't have a reproduction. The information in the question doesn't lead to this. You could make this valuable to others by providing a [mcve] in the question, but that's not been done.

Comment: I wrote this answer, because it was hard to get there. It was just a single bad line that caused the problem. I found it helpful for others with a *similar* problem to know an approach for debugging such a problem. I am not able to provide an actual MCVE, because it would be far from minimal. Thus, the question may have issues. Although, I think the answer contains helpful information for others.